# How can I get the data in DB after made changes on hibernate persistent object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm new in hibernate, I want to get some pointers here.

I have an hibernate persistent object that got a few changes by user via UI form. I need figure out the original value for the changes before it committed to DB.

I have a method something like below intend to fetch the original data from DB.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = true)
private Place getOriginalPlace(long placeid) {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Place.class, placeid);
}
```

But how comes I always get the data that has been changed by user via UI form.

Can anyone give me some pointers on this?

Comment: Well, ideally if you get the object before updating, then you would have a basis for comparison. Until you show some code of the methods are called in Controller, and the subsequent layers, it's hard to isolate.

Comment: I placed the method above and its invoker together in the same class, it was not working. Then I moved the method above to another class, I got the data expected.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please write an answer yourself and mark it as accepted.